# Verilog Iterative Circuit

Tags: verilog

I found this description in a book for a magnitude comparator, and I don't understand the explanation or why it works. I have commented everything I did understand, but that one line there just kills me:

```
//Behavioral Magnitude Comparator

module MagComp(a,b,gt);

  parameter k = 8;
  input [k-1:0] a,b;
  output gt;
  wire[k-1:0] eqi = a~^b; // returns 1 whenever corresponding bits in a and b are equal
  wire[k-1:0] gti = a&~b; // returns 1 whenever an a-bit is greater than a b-bit
  wire[k:0] gtb = {   (   (eqi[k-1:0] & gtb[k-1:0])  |  gti[k-1:0]   ) , 1'b0   }; // ?? 
  assign gt = gtb[k]; // returns 1 if a>b

endmodule
```

It looks like he's assigning gtb recursively. How can this work if gtb isn't even declared in a first instance? Why is he concatenating a 0 in the end? How can there be any sort of recursion if there aren't any sequential commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not iterating, it's just calculating the bits of `gtb` in parallel. The calculation of some bits of `gtb` depend on other bits of `gtb`.

We could rewrite the questioned line (making the substitution k=8 for simplicity) as

```
gtb[8] = ( eqi[7] & gtb[7] ) | gti[7];
gtb[7] = ( eqi[6] & gtb[6] ) | gti[6];
// ...
gtb[1] = ( eqi[0] & gtb[0] ) | gti[0];
gtb[0] = 1'b0;
```

Notice that this structure does mean that a change in the low bits of `a` or `b` could affect all the higher significance bits of `gtb`. And that these changes will have to go through several gates to *ripple* up to the high-order bits of `gtb`. As such this structure will produce longer and longer path delays as the width (`k`) is increased.

You can see similar behavior in a [*ripple-carry adder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Ripple-carry_adder)